# Good practice to concat two tensors with large size difference?

Tags: deep-learning

I'm trying to concat convolved data from 2 sources. However, there is a large size difference between the 2 sources. One is `576x720` and the other is `128x9`.

What is the best way to deal with this issue? I'm considering 2 solutions:

1. Upsampling the latter images at the pre-processing stage
2. Convolve the former images more times until it gets small enough, and then reshape both tensor to 1D

Can someone share some advice?

Comment: With a quick search on google I found this: https://medium.com/neuronio/how-to-deal-with-image-resizing-in-deep-learning-e5177fad7d89

Comment: thank you! that's a great post!

Answer (score 0):

I guess that both are viable solutions, but keep in mind that if you use convolutions, you are adding more trainable parameters and depth in your network, which may make it prone to overfitting.

The approach I would try first would be that of up/down sampling.

Keep in mind though that you can simply flatten and append the two sources to create a single row. But I'm guessing that you don't want to do that, so as not to lose 2D correlation. Just sayin..